# Problems creating a connection profile

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-code

I can't seem to create a connection profile, I follow the steps seen in videos, but none have solved my problem. I have installed the mssql extension, maybe I need to install another extension?

At the bottom right it should appear "Connected to (server_name)"

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new file and set the language type to SQL (CTRL + K + M).
2. Open the command palette with CTRL + SHIFT + P and type SQL to show the MS SQL commands.
3. Select the Connect command.
4. Select Create Connection Profile. This creates a profile to connect to your SQL Server.
5. Type your connection string and press enter.
6. Your connection string will vary but will look something like this:
   *Server=localhost\MSSQLSERVER01;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;*

References: https://dzone.com/articles/sql-with-visual-studio-code

Comment: I've already done the same steps as you've instructed, but there is still no connection

Comment: I have installed the MSSQL extension in VS Code, I don't know if I need to install some other SQL program